# automatically download file from URL and store it on Google Drive

Tags: java, url, curl, download, google-drive-api

I need to download .csv file from url and store it within specific folder on google drive...this operation has to be triggered on specific time of the day (sometimes after midnight). One of my issues is that the file is not stored on the url but it is generated after executing the call for the address.

After opening for example this url (https://member.expireddomains.net/export/pendingdelete/?export=csv&activetab=expireddomains&flimit=25&fdomain=prague) the file is being generated and stored on my computer. I need it to be generated, stored on my Google Drive folder and renamed to be report.csv or anything as such. I am sorry to ask this question if it is possible but I just now discovered the google scripts and I am looking forward to learn new things.

Thank you

Comment: Take a look at this, I will update my solution soon:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44007106/goole-drive-api-upload-fails

Comment: Thank you. Do you also know how to execute this process in google script? Or how to execute it via sites.google created website?

Comment: Hi, did you ever manage to solve this?